# Reflect 2d points with matrices over a reflectionline

Tags: c#, matrix

Given a arbitrary reflection line how can you reflect a set of points with matrices? I have tried the following but i cannot get it to work:

1. Translate the system so that P1 of the reflectionline is in the
   origin
2. Rotate the system so that the reflectionline is parallel to the Y
   axis
3. Perform a Y axis reflection
4. Undo the rotation
5. Undo the translation

Iam trying to write a method to do this for me in C# basically i give it the 2 points of the line and i get the matrix back.

Comment: It seemed the steps i wrote down are good but i made some typo in my code. I fixed this and now its working properly

Answer (score 2):

No rotations are needed since [there is a formula for reflecting about any line through the origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_rotations_and_reflections).  Let `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` be **any** two points on the reflection line.  Let's say the point you want to reflect is `(x,y)`.

1. Translate the coordinates so that `(a,b)` becomes the origin.  Then `(x,y)` becomes `(x-a,y-b)`.  This step is just vector subtraction.
2. Reflect.  This is where you need the matrix.  You will multiply the matrix by the translated vector from step 1.  Your result will be another vector (a 2-by-1 matrix).
3. Translate the coordinates back to the original system.  This is the inverse of step 1, i.e., this is vector addition that just undoes the vector subtraction from step 1.  In this step you're just adding `(a,b)` to your result from step 2.

The matrix for step 2 is:

```
H(θ) = [cos(2θ)   sin(2θ)]
       [sin(2θ)  -cos(2θ)]
```

In the matrix, θ is the angle that the (translated) reflection line makes with the positive x-axis.  As long as `a` and `c` are not equal, you can find θ by evaluating:

```
θ = arctangent( (d-b) / (c-a) )
```

You will get a value strictly between `-π/2` and `π/2`.  If `a = c`, that is, if the reflection line is vertical, then just take `θ = π/2`.  Although if the reflection line is vertical (or horizontal, in which case `θ = 0`) then you can just use well-known reflection matrices for reflecting over the y- or x-axis.

This pretty much lays out the whole process of finding and using the matrix.  It sounds like all you're asking for is finding the reflection matrix.  I don't know C# well enough to use it in an answer, but here's pseudocode:

```
// (a,b) and (c,d) are any two distinct points on the reflection line
getMatrix(double a, double b, double c, double d)
    double x11, x12, x21, x22;  // Elements of the reflection matrix

    if a == c  // If the reflection line is vertical
        x11 = -1; x12 = 0; x21 = 0; x22 = 1;
    else if b == d  // If the reflection line is horizontal
        x11 = 1; x12 = 0; x21 = 0; x22 = -1;
    else
        double θ = arctangent( (d-b) / (c-a) );

        x11 = cos(2 * θ);
        x12 = sin(2 * θ);
        x21 = x12;  // sin(2 * θ) again
        x22 = -x11;  // -cos(2 * θ)
    end if

    return Matrix(x11, x12, x21, x22);
    /*  The above line returns a matrix with the following entries:
          [ x11  x12 ]
          [ x21  x22 ]
    */
```

And here's example pseudocode for using the above pseudocode:

```
// Reflect (x,y) over the line given by the points (a,b) and (c,d)
reflectPoint(double x, double y, double a, double b, double c, double d)
    Matrix reflector = getMatrix(a, b, c, d);
    Vector v1 = new Vector(x-a, x-b);  // This is Step 1
    Vector v2 = new Vector(a, b);      // This is so we can do Step 3 later

    return reflector * v1 + v2;  // v1 already has Step 1 done
                                 // reflector * v1 is Step 2
                                 // + v2 is Step 3
```

There are more efficient ways of doing the above (like checking if one of the given points `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` is already the origin, for example) but the above should still work.

Comment: This will work too i think. The difference is that in your case more things are precalculated beforehand so this will perform more. In fact you could precalculate all the steps beforehand instead of multiplying the matrices so you only have to fill in the variables.I will keep this idea in mind if I ever run into performance issues.

Comment: @Barsonax if you're worried about performance it may be better to do this without matrices and just by using perpendicularity and the distance formula.  I haven't worked out all the details but I think which way is better might depend on how many points you need to reflect.

Comment: Using matrices is just a couple of additions and multiplications. If I really wanted to squeze every last bit of performance out of it I would precalculate and eliminate any redundant variables beforehand. The nice thing about the matrix is that once its made you can reuse it for as many points you like.

Comment: When i use the matrix to transform the points i used some custom code to speed things up instead of relying on the generic implementation of the matrix. I dont need the bottom row of the 3x3matrix for instance when transforming a 2d point. Accessing the array directly instead of the using the indexer of the matrix class also helps alot. These simple optimalisations increased the speed by a factor 5. 100 million points now get transformed in 700-900 ms (on release). I doubt i will have any performance issues.

Comment: The `reflectPoint()` code has a typo: should be `Vector v1 = new Vector(x - a, y - b);`

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the typo i made here is what my code looks like:

```
private Transformer2D Reflect(Vector2D p1, Vector2D p2)
{
        var translationMatrix = new TranslateTransformation2D(new Vector2D(0, 0) - p1);
        var inverseTranslationMatrix = new TranslateTransformation2D(p1);
        var translatedP2 = translationMatrix.Transform(p2); //What p2 would be if p1 of the line was translated to the origin.
        var angleWithYaxis = new Vector2D(0, 1).AngleBetweenTwoVectors(translatedP2);
        var rotationMatrix = new RotationTransformation2D(-angleWithYaxis * RhinoMath.Deg2Rad);
        var inverseRotationMatrix = new RotationTransformation2D(angleWithYaxis * RhinoMath.Deg2Rad);
        var reflectionMatrix = new ScaleTransformation2D(-1, 1);
        return new Transformer2D(translationMatrix, rotationMatrix, reflectionMatrix, inverseRotationMatrix, inverseTranslationMatrix);
}
```

The classes iam using just abstract the matrices:

```
public class TranslateTransformation2D : MatrixTransformation2DBase
{
    public TranslateTransformation2D(Vector2D translation)
    {
        TransformationMatrix = Matrix3x3.CreateTranslationMatrix(translation.X, translation.Y);
    }

    public TranslateTransformation2D(float x, float y)
    {
        TransformationMatrix = Matrix3x3.CreateTranslationMatrix(x, y);
    }
}
```

This is how the Matrix3x3 class looks like:

```
public class Matrix3x3 : Matrix
{
    public Matrix3x3(double m11, double m12, double m13,
                     double m21, double m22, double m23,
                     double m31, double m32, double m33)
    {
        Rows = 3;
        Cols = 3;
        Mat = new double[Rows * Cols];
        Mat[0] = m11;
        Mat[1] = m12;
        Mat[2] = m13;

        Mat[3] = m21;
        Mat[4] = m22;
        Mat[5] = m23;

        Mat[6] = m31;
        Mat[7] = m32;
        Mat[8] = m33;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 CreateTranslationMatrix(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Matrix3x3(1, 0, x,
                             0, 1, y,
                             0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 CreateScaleMatrix(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Matrix3x3(x, 0, 0,
                             0, y, 0,
                             0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 CreateIdentityMatrix()
    {
        return new Matrix3x3(1, 0, 0,
                             0, 1, 0,
                             0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 CreateRotationMatrix(double radians)
    {
        var cos = Math.Cos(radians);
        var sin = Math.Sin(radians);

        return new Matrix3x3(cos, -sin, 0,
                             sin, cos, 0,
                             0, 0, 1);

    }
```

The Transformer2D class is special here since it simply combines all the transformations into one matrix so we only have to apply this matrix to get all our transformations:

```
public class Transformer2D : MatrixTransformation2DBase
{
    public Transformer2D(params IMatrixTransformation2D[] transformations)
    {
        for (int i = transformations.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var matrixTransformation2D = transformations[i];
            if (TransformationMatrix != null)
            {
                TransformationMatrix = TransformationMatrix * matrixTransformation2D.TransformationMatrix;
            }
            else
            {
                TransformationMatrix = matrixTransformation2D.TransformationMatrix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MatrixTransformation2DBase class

```
public abstract class MatrixTransformation2DBase : IMatrixTransformation2D
{
    public Matrix3x3 TransformationMatrix { get; protected set; }

    public Vector2D Transform(Vector2D vector2Din)
    {
        return vector2Din*TransformationMatrix;
    }
}
```

I could probably make it faster in a few places but the idea is that i dont have to worry anymore about the matrices themselves unless i want some new type of transformation.

For those wondering what matrix class i use internally its this one: https://github.com/darkdragon-001/LightweightMatrixCSharp

All i did was write some conveinence around this.